# ROUNDUP Function giving error as Invalid Identifier in oracle

Tags: excel, oracle, stored-procedures

I want to use `ROUNDUP` formula of excel in my oracle procedure. But while using I am getting error as

> ROUNDUP is Invalid Identifier.

Below is my code

`SELECT ROUNDUP(15/30) FROM DUAL;`

Please suggest how can I use this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, `ROUNDUP` is not an Oracle function (which is why you get the invalid identifier error).

You could instead use `CEIL`.

```sql
SELECT CEIL(15/30) FROM DUAL;
```

> ```
> | CEIL(15/30) |
> | ----------: |
> |           1 |
> ```

If you want to round up to a given precision then you could create a user-defined function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION roundup(
  value IN NUMBER,
  precision IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 0
) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  IF precision = 0 THEN
    RETURN CEIL( value );
  ELSE
    RETURN CEIL( value * POWER( 10, precision ) ) / POWER( 10, precision );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT ROUNDUP(0.56789),
       ROUNDUP(0.56789, 1),
       ROUNDUP(0.56789, 2),
       ROUNDUP(0.56789, -1)
FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ROUNDUP(0.56789) | ROUNDUP(0.56789,1) | ROUNDUP(0.56789,2) | ROUNDUP(0.56789,-1)
> ---------------: | -----------------: | -----------------: | ------------------:
>                1 |                 .6 |                .57 |                  10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4329a438916161e4eaa7d7c84cfe2b38)*

Comment: ok, thanks for the quick response.. what can we use for `ROUNDDOWN` in oracle ?

Comment: @hud Have you tried using a search engine to do some of your own research for these questions? It takes 10 seconds to look up "oracle round down" or "oracle opposite of ceil".

Comment: Or, even, look in the room: What is the opposite of CEIL(ing)? :-)